# How to draw an arrow circle at a certain coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, foreach

I defined an arrow circle but I do not know, how to move it to a specified coordinate.

Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\foreach \x in {0,30,...,360} \draw[<-] (\x:0.35cm) -- (\x:0.7cm);    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you are going to get help much faster if you provide a full minimal example others can copy and test as is, here we have to guess the preamble and so a lot opf people mass on questions like this. (3) you might want to look up coordinate calculations (see the `calc` tikz library) and relative coordinates, hint ` ++(\x:0.7cm)` (BTW: cm is the default unit so you can leave out the `cm` part)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  pics/arcirc/.style args={#1,name=#2}{
    code={
      \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#2,>=latex]
        \foreach \x in {0,30,...,360} \draw[<-,#1] (\x:0.35cm) -- (\x:0.7cm);   
      \end{scope}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\pic at (0,0) {arcirc={red,name=a}};
\pic at (2,0) {arcirc={blue,name=b}};
\pic at (0,-2) {arcirc={green,name=c}};
\pic at (2,-2) {arcirc={cyan,name=d}};
\node at (a.center){a};
\node [draw,circle,minimum size=1pt] at (b.center){};
\draw [green](c.90)--++(0:1)node[midway,above]{text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: @Secr3t, your welcome.